# LoadRunner 11.50: lrdo_initialize_db: "OCIInitialize" error when connecting to Oracle

Tags: loadrunner

I'm running a Web(HTTP/HTML) + Oracle 2-Tier scenario in Loadrunner 11.50. the script works fine in VuGen but when run in the Controller product for 6 users, I get the following error for the first user (this user fails but the following 5 complete the scenario successfully).

The error is:

```
vuser_init.c(25): Error: lrdo_initialize_db: "OCIInitialize" return-code=100314904, error-code is unavailable.  The message text is unavailable
vuser_init.c(25): OCIErrorGet return-code=-2, recordno=2
vuser_init.c(25): lrd_initialize_db: ERROR, return-code=LRDE2009
```

N.B. "lrdo_initialize_db" (with an "o") may be a typo in the error message as the function is actually `lrd_initialize_db`. Then again, it may be an internal private function. Who knows?

I've ran the same script in VuGen (in LR v11.50) and both VuGen and Controller in LR v9.10 and do not get this error. The code pertaining to the error is to do with setting up the Oracle connection and is as follows (apologies if this seems archain [but that's exactly what it is]):

```
// Connect to Oracle server
lrd_init(&InitInfo, DBTypeVersion);
lrd_initialize_db(LRD_DBTYPE_ORACLE, 2, 0);     //Error occurs on this line...
lrd_env_init(LRD_DBTYPE_ORACLE, &OraEnv1, 0, 0);
```

My LR v11.50 set up is: Win7 on a VM (32bit), using an Oracle 11.2.0.3 server (remote) and Oracle instantclient 11.2.0.3 to provide the client libraries. My LR v9.10 (which works) is running on a physical Win XP box with full Oracle 11.1.0.6 client libraries accessing the same remote 11.2.0.3 server.

The return code seems fairly sporadic across runs.

Comment: Unearthed two additional error messages by checking the errors using the Output viewer. These must be related and are more helpful (phew). Going to try matching LRDE2009 with the content of lrd.h error code 2009 to see if it sheds any light. UPDATE - not particularly - 2009 = "An underlying database routine call failed". Think it may be Oracle instantclient install (I used the lite basic lite version too). Will upgrade and see.

Comment: Update: Still no luck with Oracle instantclient basic (non-lite) or instantclient 11.1.0.6 (in case of API change). Tried Controller running with additional debug info but nothing useful. Investigating the [Oracle API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/ociaedep001.htm#LNOCI18391) it seems the function `OCIInitialize` is deprecated but apprently "kept around for backward compatibility".

Comment: workaround: I guess, I can add one extra user to my test that will fail with the above error then at least my test will run with the correct number of users. Strange that it occurs only on the first user. (Would add this as an answer... but then don't want to discourage any better ideas coming forth.)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's too late for answer... but here it goes how I solved the "OCIInitialize Error" with Oracle 2 Tier protocol:

In you controller, open the Runtime Settings for your script.
Go to Miscellaneous options and check "Run Vuser as a process"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'll check it over when I next see the issue and report back. Not sure who/ why the downvote (it's normally courteous to leave a reason).

Comment: Can you confirm you had this error consistently, applied this change and then the error no longer occured? Did you unapply the change and see the error again? I will try it when I next see the error and report back. (BTW: I love that no-one replied to this post in 3yrs but somehow someone managed to downvote your answer in <4hrs!)